# Streaming using libvlc and libstreaming

Tags: android, libvlc, libstreaming

I'd like to get advices on how to do the following if possible:

I've given 3 android devices and I'd like to stream from one to an other (maybe backwards too) at a time but also save it on a third platform (a pc maybe to have a lot of space) for later processing. I'd like to make this pc as a "server" where I recieve a stream from device A, saving it and forwarding to device B. I also want this type of connection between device A-C and B-C at once. This is the idea in a nutshell.

What I have now is I can stream device A's camera to device B using libstreaming and libvlc to recieve it.

Is it possible to achive such system and if so how difficult is it?

Thanks in advance for any kind of reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup the stream as RTSP you can have multiple subscribers, so one device could subscribe and record to video, and the other could do whatever. They would then all get the feed at the same time, no need for extra routing.  This can all be done with libVLC, and it's not too difficult. You'll have to find examples online for the server and client. It will only get tricky if you want to stream data from memory (for server using item) or write data to memory (for client using seem) directly, but there are examples for this too.